# Delimiting aggregate output in JIT/infovis

Tags: javascript, jquery, infovis

I'm using JIT to create an area chart, but I'd like to delimit the aggregates by commas because I'm working with rather large numbers.  At the moment the output is like `26103426`, etc, but I would like to format it as `26,103,426`.  Is there a built-in way to do this?

edit: `someValue.toLocaleString()` would be perfect but I don't have access to the aggregate data as it's created in the jit.js source - I'm wondering if there's a way to do this where I don't need to drill into the source code and complicate my life/threaten my sanity when I download a new version in the future.

Comment: any update on this, dax? I'm dealing with the same issue

Comment: i ended up switching to [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) in the end. Jit is nice, but flot is very easy to use and in the end just as nice.  good luck!